# z3c.form issue: ImportError: No module named ptcompat

Tags: plone, zope, chameleon, zpt, z3c.form

Has z3c.form API changes recently. I try to do following:

```
  from z3c.form.ptcompat import ViewPageTemplateFile
  widget.template = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/minmax.pt")
```

I get:

```
  ImportError: No module named ptcompat
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [`z3c.ptcompat` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.ptcompat) instead.

The `z3c.form.ptcompat` module [was removed](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/commit/d9a62dd6777349587f2571bbcf413e4e317a85e6) for the [z3c.form 2.5.0 release](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.form#id22) in October 2011.

When using `z3c.ptcompat`, replace your import with:

```
zope.browserpage.viewpagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
widget.template = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/minmax.pt")
```

Comment: Yes. Very recent change :)